# KeyError в строке

Tags: python

Есть строка кода python:

```py
post += "&attached_media[1]={\"media_fbid\":\"somecontent\"}"
```

Её суть заключается в добавление строки текста к уже существующей переменной

Но почему-то на этой строке я получаю ошибку: `KeyError: '"media_fbid"'`

Может я что-то не так экранировал?

upd: Специально для  Viktorov

```py
post = "https://graph.facebook.com/384752669053768/photos?message={message}"
for i in range(len(attachments['photos'])):
    r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/384752669053768/photos?url={url}&published=false&access_token={token}'.format(token = settings['fb_token'], url = attachments['photos'][i]))
    r = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
    post += "&attached_media[{i}]={\"media_fbid\":\"{id}\"}".format(id = str(r['id']), i=i)
r = requests.post(post+'&access_token={token}'.format(token = settings['fb_token']))
print(r.content)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 434, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\Desktop\python\re-poster\start.py", line 45, in <module>
    post += '&attached_media[{i}]={\"media_fbid\":\"{id}\"}'.format(id = str(r['id']), i=i)
KeyError: '"media_fbid"'
```

Comment: вы что-то замалчиваете. Привидите полный код, приводящий к ошибке

Comment: Он ничего Вам не даст.

Comment: @Viktorov Добавил, но я думаю он больше Вас запутает. 
UPD: Код написанный первым в добавленном коде имеет несколько другой вид

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил полный текст.

Comment: Это по прежнему гадание по фотографии. Сделайте пожалуйста [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и добавьте полноценный код для воспроизведения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на скобки:

```
post += '&attached_media[1]={{\"media_fbid\":\"somecontent\"}}'
```

`format` определяет: `{\"media_fbid\":\"somecontent\"}` как шаблон.

Ошибка:

```
"&attached_media[{i}]={\"media_fbid\":\"{id}\"}".format(id = 'ssss', i='aaaa')
```

Рабочий вариант:

```
"&attached_media[{i}]={{\"media_fbid\":\"{id}\"}}".format(id = 'ssss', i='aaaa')
```

Красивый вариант:

```
'&attached_media[{i}]={{"media_fbid":"{id}"}}'.format(id = 'ssss', i='aaaa')
```